# NPM prefix compatibility with NVM

Tags: node.js, linux, nvm

I recently installed NVM on a linux machine with the intention of using it to upgrade node.  Now I am seeing some errors when a new terminal is first launched.

```
node: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' 
not found (required by node)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to 
""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v7.9.0 --silent` 
to unset it.
```

There are two issues here: 
1.  Node is requiring `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' but cannot find it.
2.  npm config "prefix" option is not compatible with NVM

These errors were not occurring before I installed NVM.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

For the first issue,

run the following command,

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

For the second issue try resetting npm config to default,

```
echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)
npm config --global edit
```

if this does not work try

```
sudo npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

**UPDATE**

For Debian Wheezy and earlier only:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

Try this for the first issue again,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And for the second issue,

```
echo "" > $(npm config get userconfig)
npm config edit
```

**UPDATE 2**

To Reinstall Node.js and npm in your scenario use the following,

```
sudo apt-get install curl python-software-properties
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo bash -

sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge npm
```

Then,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

Comment: Hi Kalana, I have run your commands, and the errors are still occurring the same way. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: did you try the Update

Comment: After the first command (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test) I get the error:  sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found.   For the second issue, my error is still occurring.  Here is my Linux distro if that helps:   Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)

Comment: ok, I added the solution for wheezy and before first thing in the update.

Comment: btw did you try reinstalling both node and nvm

Comment: I tried your suggestions, and the issues are still occurring.  I am getting this warning:  npm WARN npm npm does not support Node.js v0.10.42
npm WARN npm You should probably upgrade to a newer version of node as we
npm WARN npm can't make any promises that npm will work with this version.
npm WARN npm You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/

Comment: I am trying to upgrade node with nvm, but i cannot as it is stuck on this deprecated version.

Comment: I reinstalled Node and NPM, the errors are all still there.  When I run echo "" > $(npm config get userconfig) I get this:  /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
bash: $(npm config get userconfig): ambiguous redirect

Comment: what does npm -v and  node -v gives as output